# Create Internet Explorer page shortcut with VBS

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

I'm attempting to create a VB script to create a `.lnk` that points to a webpage opened in Internet Explorer:

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sLinkFile = "C:\users\admin\Desktop\My Website.lnk" 
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) 
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://192.168.1.1" 
oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\" 
oLink.Description = "My Website" 
oLink.Save
```

But I'm getting the following error when I try to execute:

`.\CreateShortcut.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument`

I'm assuming it has something to with my syntax on the `oLink.TargetPath` variable, but I'm not sure what is wrong. I've tried escaping the quotes but that didn't work.

What is my invalid call or argument in that script?

Note that I can't just link to the webpage and not `iexplore.exe`, as I need this page to *only* open in Internet Explorer, not whichever browser happens to be default.

Comment: "What is my invalid call or argument in that script?" - Based on the error message, 4th line, which matches up to the answer that was submitted.

Comment: @ramhound I thought maybe my syntax was off. Didn't know the argument had to be in a separate property. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the MSDN page on the `TargetPath` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67(v=vs.84).aspx):

> This property is for the shortcut's target path only. Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's [sic] property.

Including the URL in the target path makes the path invalid - filenames cannot include colons. The script will work if you specify only the path to Internet Explorer in `TargetPath`. You can then place the page URL in the [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7kaky2(v=vs.84).aspx) property:

```
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
oLink.Arguments = "http://192.168.1.1"
```

Comment: Guess I need to clean my glasses, I was just looking at that page. That did the trick. Thanks!